# Mysql limit the number of returned results based on the unique values from a single column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables,

```
Product_to_categories   => contains two columns (Category_id, Product_id)
Product => contains a few columns (product_id, name, sku, ...)
categories => contains a few columns (category_id, name, ....)
```

I would like to get a result set for the first 10 unique category_id's joined with the product table, a category can have many product assigned to it, i want all products within one category returned, but i'd like to only get the products from the first 8 categories...

Current query:

```
SELECT p2c.category_id, p.pname, c.category_name
FROM product p LEFT JOIN   product_to_category p2c
ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id)
Left Join category c (p2c.category_id = c.category) LIMIT 0,8
```

Current output

```
catID  |    p.name   |    catName |<br/>
1      |     docs    |      shoe<br/>
1      |     bob      |     shoe<br/>
1      |     mom      |     shoe<br/>
1      |     cat      |     shoe<br/>
1      |     dang     |     shoe<br/>
1      |     kit      |     shoe<br/>
2      |     pis      |     book<br/>
2      |     jiz      |     book<br/>
```

Currently i only get the first 8 results regardsless, however i am looking to get the following output:

```
catID  |    p.name   |    catName |<br/>
1      |     docs    |      shoe<br/>
1      |     bob      |     shoe<br/>
1      |     mom      |     shoe<br/>
1      |     cat      |     shoe<br/>
1      |     dang     |     shoe<br/>
1      |     kit      |     shoe<br/>
2      |     pis      |     book<br/>
2      |     jiz      |     book<br/>
3      |     docs     |     shirt<br/>
3      |     bob      |     shirt<br/>
3      |     mom      |     shirt<br/>
4      |     cat      |     light<br/>
4      |     dang     |     light<br/>
5      |     kit      |     sound<br/>
6      |     pis      |     mic<br/>
6      |     jiz      |     mic<br/>
7      |     docs     |     pen<br/>
7      |     bob      |     pen<br/>
7      |     mom      |     pen<br/>
7      |     cat      |     pen<br/>
8      |     dang     |     lace<br/>
8      |     kit      |     lace<br/>
8      |     pis      |     lace<br/>
8      |     jiz      |     lace<br/>
```

i would like the resultset to contain results of all products that are assigned to the first 8 categories...

Please advise.
Thanks
Hadi

Comment: 8 or 10 categories? what if some category has no products, next category should be displayed?

Comment: Your question doesn't really define what you want to do well enough. You could do the things you want with subqueries, possibly

Comment: If you only need products from the first 8 categories, how are you going to have the last two categories (without products) in the same table?

Comment: Sorry, i should have been more clear in my question, i don't always need product only from the first 8 categories, i will be using pagination along that, so i will be needing product from 0,8 categories at the first page, 8-16 second page and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure why your query is starting from the product table, so I'm not going to - but aside from this, I think what you need is:

```
SELECT c.category_id, p.pname, c.category_name
FROM category c 
    INNER JOIN product_to_category pc ON c.category_id = pc.category_id
    INNER JOIN product p ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE c.category_id in (SELECT TOP 8 category_id FROM Category)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have been more clear in my question, i don't always need product only from the first 8 categories, i will be using pagination along that, so i will be needing product from 0,8 categories at the first page, 8-16 second page and so on, i believe your solution above always returns the top 8 categories, i think i need to use limit 0,8 to include pagination in the whole deal?